# RedHat 7.6\8.0 and LSI SAS 2008 controllers

Tags: centos, redhat, lsi, kernel-modules, hba

Starting with versions 7.6 \ 8.0beta, RedHat has disabled support for SAS controllers on the LSI SAS 2008 chip. However, in Fedora 29 with the kernel 4.18, the controllers work. So, RedHat simply assembled the mpt3sas kernel module without the support of these chips. How do I activate support for these chips back?